# Android Emulator horribly slow - Dell Latitude D531

Tags: android, emulation

I try to run the hello android example on my notebook Dell Latitude D531 which has following specification:
http://img573.imageshack.us/img573/9990/ntbspecification.png

I set the virtual device as following:
http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/4070/myavd.png

(Sorry for links instead of images, but I don't have enough reputation points yet)

When I created this AVD and started it, it took like two hours to start, after that, the device was unusably slow. I read the other topics here, where people wrote about their experience with starting of the emulator, that it took long ... like 15 minutes when they started it for the first time. But in my case it takes not minutes but hours, and when start is completed, it isn't usable at all.

What are your suggestions for improvement of speed or performance in this case?
What do I do wrong? - is my notebook too slow, is the configuration bad, whatever you think could help me ...

With regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. Your notebook CPU is a bit weak
2. The 3.0 emulator is unusable, IMHO, unless you increase the "Device ram size" to 1024 in the AVD configuration (your 2nd screenshot), which may be more than your PC can afford to give the emulator, particularly if you are also running Eclipse, since you only have 3GB of RAM
3. The 3.0 emulator is slow in general, even on faster hardware

Right now, I recommend that you use an earlier API level (e.g., API Level 8) for your emulator, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the snapshot feature helps, sometimes.  The emulator is pretty unreliable. If you're doing any amount of dev I would get a real device. Even an outdated "cheap & cheerful" one from ebay would give you a big productivity boost.